# Why does this number parser not correctly parse doubles?

Tags: java, parsing

I've written a basic number parser that I believe should work for both doubles and integers. However, when called to parse a number, it only works with int types, when the number is a double (which it knows by reaching a decimal point) it simply stops parsing. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this code:

(Note: the parser is parsing numbers from a file which is previously read into a char array. I know that the contents of the file are read into the array correctly because I print the array contents and it contains the correct contents)

**My Number Parser Function:**

```
NumReturn numberParser(int cIndex) { // current index of array where num is
    // found
    int num = 0;
    double dnum;
    // int[] result = new int[2];
    while (Character.isDigit(Lexer.fileContents[cIndex]) == true) {
        num = num * 10 + Character.getNumericValue(Lexer.fileContents[cIndex]);
        System.out.println(num);
        cIndex++;
        if (cIndex >= Lexer.fileContents.length)
            break;
    }

    try {
        if (Lexer.fileContents[cIndex] == '.') {
            dnum = (double) num;
            int n = 1;
            while (Character.isDigit(Lexer.fileContents[cIndex++]) == true) {
                dnum = dnum + Character.getNumericValue(Lexer.fileContents[cIndex]) / (10 * n);
                n++;
                System.out.println(dnum);
                cIndex++;
                if (cIndex >= Lexer.fileContents.length)
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("Double Value:" + dnum);
            return new NumReturn(dnum, cIndex);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Int Value:" + num);
    return new NumReturn(num, cIndex);

}
```

**NumReturn class:** //even though you probably dont need to see this

```
package jsmash;

public class NumReturn {
    int value;
    double dvalue;
    int pointerLocation;
    NumReturn(int value, int pointerLocation) {
        this.value = value;
        this.pointerLocation = pointerLocation;
    }
    NumReturn(double dvalue, int pointerLocation) {
        this.dvalue = value;
        this.pointerLocation = pointerLocation;
    }
}
```

**Test Cases:**

```
323 --> parses correctly and prints 323
323.54 --> stops parsing after the decimal and prints 323.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this statement:

```
dnum = dnum + Character.getNumericValue(Lexer.fileContents[cIndex]) / (10 * n);
```

The `/` operator has higher precedence, so it is evaluated as this:

```
dnum = dnum + (Character.getNumericValue(Lexer.fileContents[cIndex]) / (10 * n));
```

Both sides of the `/` operator are of type `int`, so this is an integer division. You are dividing a number < 10 by a number >= 10, so you are always getting 0 as integer division truncates. You need to make at least one of the operands a `double`, and then it will do floating-point division. However, that's not the end of your problems. Your code divides by 10, 20, 30, .... You want it to divide by 10, 100, 1000, .... Also, you are advancing cIndex twice: inside the while condition, and again in the loop. You should only do it once.

```
        ++cIndex; // Advance past the decimal point.
        double n = 10;
        while (Character.isDigit(Lexer.fileContents[cIndex])) {
            dnum += Character.getNumericValue(Lexer.fileContents[cIndex]) / n;
            n *= 10;
```

Comment: Ah how could I be such an idiot. PEMDAS Lol. Thank you. Haven't gotten a chance to try it yet since I'm not on a computer though which is why I haven't accepted this answer. I'll do it as soon as I get a chance to test.

Comment: I've made a few corrections to my answer in the last few minutes. I haven't tested it myself but I think it should be ok now.

Comment: Ok thanks again. Helps a lot :D I have been stuck on that for days.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
dnum = dnum + Character.getNumericValue(Lexer.fileContents[cIndex]) / (10 * n);
```

to:

```
dnum = dnum + (Character.getNumericValue(Lexer.fileContents[cIndex]) * 1.0) / (10 * n);
```

In your current code, you are dividing `Character.getNumericValue(Lexer.fileContents[cIndex])`, which is an `int`, by a `double`- this is always equaling `0.0`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I really appreciate the help so +1. However I am going to accept the other answer because it has more details and anyone in the future with this problem might get more from that.